# C# Uri AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory relative path

Tags: c#

How do you get the relative path to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory into a Uri.

I need to step up "cd ......" from the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory and then down to other folders.

Do you know how?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to step up one ore more folders and then down, you could use something like this.

To get a file two folders up:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"..\\..\\Program.cs"
```

To get a file two folders up and one down:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "..\\..\\Properties\\AssemblyInfo.cs"
```

If you just want the path you could do something like this:

```
Path.GetFullPath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "..\\..\\Properties\\");
```

Comment: Thank your for your suggestion. I have clicked it as useful.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following:

System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"......\www\");